# Передача текста из PHP файла с помощью AJAX и JSON

Tags: ajax, php, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Суть в том, что функция `$news->addNews` выполняется, но картинка "загрузки" не удаляется и срабатывает `error: function() { }`

php файл:

```
    if(isset($_GET['addnews'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['response']) && !isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Внимание! Вы не авторизованы."));
        return;
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['response']) && strlen($_POST['title']) < 6) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Внимание! Название новости не должно быть менее 6 символов."));
        return;         
    }   
    $news->addNews($_SESSION['userid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text']);
    $smarty->display("template/addnews.tpl");       
}
```

addnews.tpl (сам ajax запрос):

```
<script>
$("#send").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "news.php?addnews",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            title: $("#title").val(),
            text: $("#text").val(),
            response: 1
        },
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loading").css({
                "display": "inline"
            });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var error = $(".message").html(data.error);
            $(error).css({
                "color": "red",
                "font-weight": "bold"
            });
            $(error).animate({
                "opacity": "0.0"
            }, 5000);             
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }).done(function(){
        $(".loading").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

`$_GET` использую для того, чтобы получить ссылку вида: `news.php?addnews`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
// ... прочее ...
$news->addNews($_SESSION['userid'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text']);
ob_start();
$smarty->display("template/addnews.tpl");
$response = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Вам должен вернуться ответ, содержащий шаблон. Если всё верно, то остаётся полученные данные установить в нужный блок.

Comment: @Deonis, выводит на странице: "\r\n\r\n\t\r\n \r\n\t\t

Comment: @evansive, сложно что-то сказать, не видя всю картину в целом. Убедитесь, что шаблонизация проходит успешно. Уберите пока все проверки и прочее, а оставьте только вывод данных.

P.S. В отладчике смотрите, что и в каком виде возвращается ответом

Comment: @Deonis, дело в том, что если убрать json из ajax-запроса, то все работает отлично...

Comment: Я вот подумал, может это из-за того, что указано: dataType: "json"?

Может нужно как-то через JSON.parse?